# How to change/edit the text of a paragraph/div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, edit, paragraph

Now what I'm trying to do is to change/edit the text of a paragraph and/or a div tag. Both elements are created dynamically with their own incremental id. I want the user to be able to enter a text in a textarea which would change the text of a paragraph or div. When they select the paragraph or div a textarea should appear that way users can update the text.

Problem:
Since I have set the incremental ID on both elements its hard for me to get them.

How can I achieve this?

This is the code I've been working on

http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/93/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var pid = 1;
$("#addP").on({
    click: function(){
        var pr = $('<p />').attr({'class':'test', 'id':'paragraph_' + pid}).text('This is a paragraph ' + pid);
        var d = $("#Test");
        var pclone = $(pr).clone();
        pclone.on({
            mouseenter: function(){    
                $(this).addClass("inside");
            },
            mouseleave: function(){                             
                $(this).removeClass("inside"); 
            },
                    });
        pclone.appendTo(d);
pid++;
    }
});
var divid = 1;
$("#addDiv").on({
    click: function(){
        var pr = $('<div />').attr({'class':'test', 'id':'div_' +     divid}).text('This is a div ' + divid);
        var d = $("#Test");
        var pclone = $(pr).clone();
        pclone.on({
            mouseenter: function(){    
                $(this).addClass("inside");
            },
            mouseleave: function(){                             
                $(this).removeClass("inside"); 
            },
                    });
        pclone.appendTo(d);
divid++;
    }
});




var div =  $('<div class="customD" id="d"></div>');
var del = $('<a href="#" class="delete" id="erase">Delete</a>');

$('#updateP').hide();
$('#updateD').hide();

var flag = false;
$("#Test").on("click", "p", function(){ 
var cur = $(this).css("background-color");


   if(cur=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") {  
       if(flag==false){
           $('#updateP').show();
            $('#updateD').show();

    $(this).css("background-color","#FDD").addClass("help insider").after(div);
flag = true;

}

}
else { 
 $('#updateP').hide();
 $('#updateD').hide();

            $(this).css("background-color","white").removeClass('help insider');
 $(div).remove();
flag = false;
}    
$(div).append(del);  


$(".delete").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
$(this).remove();
flag = false;

});


}); 

$('#updateP').change(function(){
var a = $(this).val();
$('p').text(a);

});
id++;     
});
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="addP">P tag</a> or <a href="#" id="addDiv">Div   tag</a><br/><br/>
    <textarea id="updateP"></textarea>
    <textarea id="updateD"></textarea>

    <div id="Test"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to store the div id somewhere in the code where you're generating and adding the Div into the Document? This can then be retrieved by the update code. Another option is that you generate the update code as well(a script tag element) and attach it to the textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a much simpler solution than the big page of code you're trying. The best way to do this is:

- Set an event that saves the clicked div/p
- Make a JavaScript function to display a textarea
- Fill the textarea with the contents of the div/p
- Add a save button that updates the clicked div/p
- Add a close button for when they want to hide the textarea again

I've made a **[simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRH/467S5/)** that illustrates this perfectly.

EDIT: I've updated the jsFiddle.

Comment: I understant your solution but really that's not what I'm looking for here is a link if you want to check my work at http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/93/    Thanks!

Comment: @jQueryster: I've updated the jsFiddle link to do what I think you want.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, the update you did was what I needed, had to adjusted to my code. I'm running into another problem according to my ideas: If the user clicks on the paragraph, then show #editorForParagraph or if user clicks on the div, then show #editorForDiv, in other words each of the elements should have their own individual editor. If you want, I can post another question. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! I was trying very hard yesterday and I just couldnt figure it out (It doesnt take long to know if im a beginner, totally knew to Javascript/jQuery). Thanks Grandmaster Benjamin!

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right and that the incremental id part for div and paragraph are the same, you may try this: add a class say `div_class` to each div.
Then

```
$('.div_class').keydown(function() {//Use appropriate listener
//get the incremental_id part from the div
var incremental_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);

var text = $(this).text();
//Copy the text into para using appropriate function. I have assumed text will work.
$('#para_'+incremental_id).text(text);
});
```

I have assumed input in div and it is to be copied in para. Use according to your need.
Use On/Live as needed.