# jQuery alters page - but how/where do I "acquire" the changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

This post by @BenjaminRH ([How to change/edit the text of a paragraph/div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476533/how-to-change-edit-the-text-of-a-paragraph-div-using-jquery)) provides exactly the sort of functionality I'm trying to build on.

By clicking on a button, a new paragraph is created on the page, which  can be edited and saved to the page.

I want to save it to a database. When I look at the page source after editing, I don't see the changes there, which doesn't surprise me... but I don't know where to "capture" the changed text so that I can validate and post to mySQL.

Comment: look in live html in your browser dev tools, source is only what gets sent from server

Comment: Ahh, right.. that's good. Of course not being able to submit a <p> element in a form $_POST raises other issues.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a javascript library - which runs client side. If you wanted to save that data into the database - you would have to send it to the server (php/asp/mvc etc) using ajax and then insert the data into the database.

See the [jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function for details on how to accomplish sending data asynchronously.

1. Create the data in javascript that you want to show and save in database.
2. Wrap the data in JSON and use ajax to POST the data to the server side code
3. Server-side retrieve the posted data and parse it into something usable
4. Server-side write a script to insert the data into the database.
5. Handle any errors that may occur.

Pseudo-code:

```
// step 1
var someData = 'this is my data';
$("#myDiv").html(someData);

// step 2
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json', // <-- if the data is complex and needs to be object-oriented
  url: "some.php", // <-- that is the file that will handle the post server-side.
  data: JSON.stringify({ someData }) // <-- just pass someData if your data is not complex
})
.always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus != "success") {
              // step 5: handle error.
              alert("Error: " + jqXHR.statusText); //error is always called .statusText
        } else {
              alert("Success: " + jqXHR.response); //might not always be named .response
        }});
```

Comment: Ok,  makes sense.  Can you explain 5 high level steps,  so I can go and learn how?  I am using Code Igniter as my MVC on PHP...  never touched Ajax.

Comment: How's that? I don't have much experience with code igniter, but you should be able to find a way to get the request object that gets POSTed from this request. Keep in mind this is asynchronous, which means it happens while keeping the webpage completely unaffected (except if you explicitly change the html like line 3 above or the alerts)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to solve it for myself, without using ajax. I took the example from  (How to change/edit the text of a paragraph/div using jQuery?) and modified it by placing the elements in an (html) form.

The second modification was to use `<textarea>` elements, not `<p>` elements, as `<p>` elements cannot be posted.

As @caspian pointed out (in the comments) those two steps do populate the `$_POST` array and away we go.